# A bad result of the comparison - PHP

Tags: php, comparison

I have a function that connects to the database and returns a number and a second function, which returns the size of a file.
If I use the echo function to view the results functions: variable1 = 1345064, and variable2 = 135

,but when I use a comparison, go me incorrect result:

```
if($variable1 < $variable2)

{

   echo 'This code is displayed';

}

else

{

   echo 'This code should display';

}
```

what's wrong?

---

My source code:

```
<?php
include 'funkcje.inc';
    $login = $_GET['login'];
            $fsize = WielkoscPliku2($file);

    $tmp = $fsize / 1000000;

$zmienna1 = SprTransfer($login);
$zmienna2 = floor($tmp);

      if($zmienna1 < $zmienna2)
    {
        echo "This code is displayed";  
    }
    else
    {
            echo "This code should be displayed";
         }
    ?>
```

SprTransfer function:

```
<?php
require "connection.php";
connection(); 

...

function SprTransfer($login)
{
$zapytanie = "SELECT `transfer` FROM `uzytkownicy` WHERE `nick`='$login'";
    $idzapytania = mysql_query($zapytanie);
    $sprwaznosc = mysql_fetch_row($idzapytania);
    return $sprwaznosc[0];
}
?>
```

---

Main file:

```
include 'funkcje.inc';

    $login = $_GET['login'];

            $fsize = WielkoscPliku2($file);


    $tmp = $fsize / 1000000;


$zmienna1 = SprTransfer($login);

$zmienna2 = floor($tmp);


      if($zmienna1 < $zmienna2)

    {

        echo "This code is displayed";



    }

    else

    {

            echo "This code should be displayed";

         }




function.inc file:


require "connection.php";

connection(); 



function SprTransfer($login)

{

$zapytanie = "SELECT `transfer` FROM `uzytkownicy` WHERE `nick`='$login'";

    $idzapytania = mysql_query($zapytanie);

    $sprwaznosc = mysql_fetch_row($idzapytania);

    return $sprwaznosc[0];


}
```

Comment: In my real code i have '$' before variable1 and variable2

Comment: edit the post to reflect that

Comment: Could you post the original value, before the floor($tmp); ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how, but it looks like you are interpreting your numbers as strings.

For example this will display `This code is displayed`:

```
<?php

    $variable1 = "1345064a";
    $variable2 = "135a";
    if ($variable1 < $variable2) {
        echo "This code is displayed";
    }
    else {
        echo "This code should be displayed";
    }

    // Output: This code is displayed
?>
```

### **[exmple](http://codepad.viper-7.com/mJ6UGE)**

Cast your variables to `int`

```
<?php

    $variable1 = "1345064a";
    $variable2 = "135a";
    if ((int) $variable1 < (int) $variable2) {
        echo "This code is displayed";
    }
    else {
        echo "This code should be displayed";
    }

    // Output: This code should be displayed
?>
```

### **[example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/35T6rE)**

### Debugging:

You can check the type of your variables using **[`gettype()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettype.php)**. You should never use the output of `gettype()` to test for one particular type, since the output string is liable to change from one version of PHP to another.

Comment: how to check whether a variable is a string? And how can I possibly compare those variables?

Comment: @oski225 - I edited it into my answer - `gettype()`. When strings are compared, the one that comes first alphabetically is "less than" the other.

Comment: @oski225 - That's formatted badly, it should be `(int) $variable` - Note the dollar sign ( `$` ). Click on the example links and play with those.

Comment: My mistake again, but (int)$variable1 is 0 too.

I checked the function gettype:

variable1 is string
variable2 is double

Comment: You can try use intval($var) .

Comment: I try do: if((double) $zmienna1 < (double) $zmienna2), but result is the same. intval($var) doesn't work too.

Comment: @oski225 - try `echo $zmienna1 . "\n"; echo $zmienna2 . "\n"; if((float) $zmienna1 < (float) $zmienna2){ ... } else { ... }` The `echo` will allow you to see the values you are working with and go from there...... What are the 2 strings, exactly?

Answer (score 4):

You are using variable names wrong. A variable needs to be preceded by a `$`.

```
$variable1 = 4;
$variable2 = 5; 

if ($variable1 < $variable2) {
    echo 'Yep';
}else {
    echo 'Nope';
}
```

You should look into the [basic syntax of PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.php) namely the [Variables Section](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.php).

Comment: My real code is:

$zmienna1 = SprTransfer($login);

$zmienna2 = floor($tmp);


      if($zmienna1 < $zmienna2)

 {

     echo 'pff';

 }

 else

 {

           echo 'OK';
         }

Answer (score 2):

maybe the $ before variables:

```
if($variable1 < $variable2)
```

Comment: In this code, I made a mistake, but in real code, I have a "$".
Sorry.

Comment: My real code is:

$zmienna1 = SprTransfer($login);

$zmienna2 = floor($tmp);


      if($zmienna1 < $zmienna2)

 {

     echo 'pff';

 }

 else

 {

           echo 'OK';

         }

Answer (score 1):

assuming that missing the $ is just a typo ...

when you run into this type of problem, the best thing is to post a full working code sample. for example, the code below works as it should. it displays "This code should be displayed".
what happens when you run it? what is the difference between this code and yours? answer those two questions and you'll be at least pointed to your answer:

```
<?php

    $variable1 = 1345064;
    $variable2 = 135;
    if ($variable1 < $variable2) {
        echo "This code is displayed";
    }
    else {
        echo "This code should be displayed";
    }
?>
```